# parse time in utc javascript nan

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I have time like :
`Sat Jan 04 2020 02:12:00 GMT+0300`

How can I convert it into this `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` format or UTC time format?

In javascript ?

I have tried `console.log(Date.UTC(Date.parse('Sat Jan 04 2020 02:12:00 GMT+0300')));` it gives me NaN

Comment: [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) expects date components, starting with year. You could use `new Date(...)`, it parses your string correctly.

Comment: UTC is not a format, it's a time standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `new Date()` method.

```js
console.log(new Date('Sat Jan 04 2020 02:12:00 GMT+0300'))
```

To use custom formatting try making use of [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

```js
console.log(moment(new Date('Sat Jan 04 2020 02:12:00 GMT+0300')).format('ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss zz YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/1.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Please note :** Latest versions of Moment js 1.6.0+ does not support timezone functionality.

Comment: how can I convert date in `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` format ?

Comment: can you do this in react.js please ??

Comment: React JS has moment npm library package. You can use that

Comment: but it has no method to convert

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592547/react-js-moment-js-no-function) one