# react.js moment.js no function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
console.log(moment(new Date('Sat Jan 04 2020 02:12:00 GMT+0300')).format('ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss zz YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/1.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I can parse time using moment.js, how can I do the same thing in react.js ?

I used `"react-moment": "^0.9.7"`, all it give me is this : `Module not found: Can't resolve 'moment' in ..`

Comment: Maybe you imported <sctipt moment...> after the import of your script  ?

Comment: Cant you show here the whole .html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `moment` package(library)

```
npm i moment // or
yarn add moment
```

Code

```
import moment from "moment";
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let str = "Sat Jan 04 2020 02:12:00 GMT+0300";
    let formated = moment(str).format("ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss zz YYYY");
    return (
      <>
        <h2>{formated}</h2>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to install the `moment` package from npm or yarn.

```
npm install moment --save   # npm
yarn add moment             # Yarn
```

I would prefer you to use the `moment` package itself rather than using `react-moment`.

```js
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
```

Moment JS [Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)